# Controlling the subcaption space in memoir

Tags: spacing, captions, memoir, subfloats

Memoir provides these two declarations to control the vertical space surrounding  a subcaption:

```
\tightsubcaptions
\loosesubcaptions
```

I was wondering if there is a way to control this spacing more accurately; perhaps using something that allows me to specify exactly the amount of spacing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\tightsubcaptions` command is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\tightsubcaptions}{%
  \subfloattopskip = 5\p@
  \subfloatcapskip  = \z@
  \subfloatcaptopadj = 3\p@
  \subfloatbottomskip = 5\p@
  \subfloatlabelskip = 0.33em \@plus 0.07em \@minus 0.03em
  \subfloatcapmargin = \z@
  \@tightsubcaptrue
}
```

So you can play with the various skip values (presumably the `\subfloattopskip` and `\subfloatbottomskip`.)

You shouldn't need to redefine the `\tightsubcaptions` command, but just change the sub values after setting `\tightsubcaptions`.

For example, you can change the `\subfloattopskip` to 0 like so:

```
\setlength{\subfloattopskip}{0pt}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan. Would you mind explaining how I can change the value of `\subfloattopskip` after setting `\tightsubcaptions`?

Comment: @roseck You can just use `\setlength`.  I've added an example.