# remove blank space before text under figure when using sidecaption and memoir class

Tags: captions, margins, memoir, subfloats, minipage

As you can see, when using sidecaption in memoir class, the text in the margin control the text position under the tabulate.

[image]

Is it possible to remove all this blankspace under the tabular subcaption ?

Oh, and do you think is it possible to center the table in the sidecaption ?

Here the Mwe

```
% !TEX encoding =  UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amstext}    % defines the \text command, needed here
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SIDE CAPTION 
\newsubfloat{figure}{}
\newsubfloat{table}{}

\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}

\captiontitlefont{\normalfont}% title font
\precaption{\raggedright}% for Caption N
\captiondelim{\newline}% newline*
\captionstyle{\raggedright}% for title
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\onelineskip}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\renewcommand*{\sidecapstyle}{%
 \ifscapmargleft
    \captionstyle{\justifying\scriptsize}%
  \else
    \captionstyle{\justifying\scriptsize}%
  \fi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SUB CAPTION 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49448/controlling-the-subcaption-space-in-memoir
\loosesubcaptions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{Application des règles de dominance aux points $e$ et $f$. \\ \\
           \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}
                    \toprule
                     & f1 & f2 \\
                    \midrule
                    e      & 0.5    &  4   \\
                    f      & 0.5    & 5,5  \\
                    \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}\\ \\ 
            (a) $e \prec f$ car e est bien le meilleur sur au moins un des deux objectifs, et n'est pas pire sur aucuns des autres objectifs ($e \preceq f$ \\ )
            (b) f ne domine pas e car f n'est pas meilleur sur aucun des deux objectifs et il est pire sur au moins un des deux objectif}[tab:pranking]

        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \subbottom[e est faiblement dominé par f ?]{
                \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}
                    \toprule
                        & f1 & f2 \\
                    \midrule
                    e \leq f & \text{true} & \text{true} \\
                    e < f   & \text{false}  & \text{true} \\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
            \label{subfig_xyespaceSolutionCandidate:a}}
         \end{minipage}\hspace{1em}
         \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \subbottom[f est faiblement dominé par e ?]{
                \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}
                    \toprule
                      & f1 & f2 \\
                    \midrule
                    f \leq  e & \text{true} & \text{false} \\
                    f < e  & \text{false}  & \text{false} \\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
            \label{subfig_xyespaceSolutionCandidate:a}}
        \end{minipage}
  \end{sidecaption}
\end{table}

Les solutions admise parmis le front de pareto (voir figure \ref{fig:frontoptimal}) sont donc ici tout ceux qui ne sont pas dominé faiblement ($\preceq$), ce qui revient à exclure les points $f$ et $l$ du front optimum $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ car ils sont dominés faiblement ($e \preceq f$); alors que dans le cadre d'une dominance forte ($\prec \prec$), ceux-ci aurait fait partie du front $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,l\}$. En effet si on prend toujours le cas de $e$ et $f$, la condition testant que $e$ est strictement meilleur que $f$ sur tout les objectif n'est pas rempli. %Cet ensemble de cardinalité forcément inférieure ou égale est qualifié \enquote{d'ensemble fort non dominé} (\textit{Strongly non dominated set}).

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better *hack* might be to use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\m@mscapopboxes}{%
  \m@mcalcscapraise%
  \usebox{\m@mscap@fbox}%\m@mscapcheckside
  \ifscapmargleft%
  \rlap{\kern-\m@mscaplkern%
    \raisebox{\m@mscapraise}{\smash[b]{\usebox{\m@mscap@capbox}}}%
  }%
  \else%
    \rlap{\kern\sidecapsep%
      \raisebox{\m@mscapraise}{\smash[b]{\usebox{\m@mscap@capbox}}}%
    }%
  \fi%
  \gdef\m@mscapthisside{}%
  \@mem@scap@afterhook%
}
\makeatother
```

I added the `\smash[b]`. Basically sidecaption makes the assumption that captions are *short* and ends up making two boxes next to each other, one with the figure and the other protruning into the margin. It does not make any attempt to hide the size of what ever goes into the margin.

Comment: @reyman64, notice that it requires `amsmath`, standard `\smash` does not have the extra option

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty trick, add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\endsidecaption}{\m@mscapend@fbox\refstepcounter\@captype\m@mscaplabel%
    \begin{lrbox}{\m@mscap@capbox}%
        \raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{% This line is added, to remove the depth of the box
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\sidecapwidth}%
          \sidecapstyle\@caption\@captype[\m@mscap@fortoc]{\m@mscap@forcap}%
        \end{minipage}%
        }%
    \end{lrbox}\m@mscapopboxes}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Hi, hum it doesn't resolve the problem on my real use case, don't know why ..